# parameter-pack-like usages acted wired

Tags: c++, c++11, parameters

I want to have a function with a variadic parameter number, there are two ways to achieve this
 - parameter pack from C++11
 - va_list from C lang
 I think. The C way is not good, because it has no type information provided

official [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) is something used in template classes/functions, but it is compilable when being outside of a template, which acted wired, what's the right way to achieve this?

```cpp
#include<iostream>

class A {
 public:
  int a;
  int P(A* args ...) {
    for(A *m: { args  }) {
      std::cout << m->a << " ";
    }
  }
};


int main() {
  A AA[10];
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    AA[i].a = i+1;
  }
  AA[0].P(AA+1, AA+2, AA+3, AA+4);
}
```

This c++11 code printf `2`, which is far away from what I expected to be `2 3 4 5`, why?

Comment: Because "`{ args }`" evaluates to a one-element array. Pop quiz: `int a[]={1}`: how big is this array?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik 42.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int P(A* args ...)
```

`A* args` is an ordinary declarator without a template parameter pack.  Therefore, the `...` is interpreted as declaring a variadic function (i.e., the `va_args` way) instead of a variadic template.  This declaration is equivalent to:

```
int P(A* args, ...)
```

To declare a variadic template, you need a template parameter pack and a function parameter pack, as in:

```
template <typename... Args>
void f(Args... args);
```

Here, `Args` is the template parameter pack and `args` is the function parameter pack.

Then you need to use pack expansion to traverse the pack.  In C++11 there is no trivial way of doing this, so the common (hack) way is

```
int arr[] = {0, (std::cout << args->a << " ", 0)...};
```

The *braced-init-list* ensures that the pack is traversed in order.  The leading `0` prevents zero-sized arrays when the pack is empty.  Putting everything together:

```
template <typename... Args>
void f(Args... args)
{
    int arr[] = {0, (std::cout << args->a << " ", 0)...};
    (void)arr; // to suppress unused variable warning
}
```

---

Since C++17, use a fold expression instead of the hack way:

```
template <typename... Args>
void f(Args... args)
{
    ((std::cout << args->a << " "), ...);
}
```

(The parentheses are necessary for syntax reasons.)

---

If you want to make your function exactly equivalent to a non-template function like `void f(A*, A*, A*)`, things get a bit complicated.  First you have to use perfect forwarding to avoid decay:

```
template <typename... Args>
void f(Args&&... args);
```

and then use `static_cast<A*>(std::forward<Args>(args))` instead of `args` in the function.  And to make it work with overload resolution, you need to use SFINAE: (need to `#include <type_traits>`)

```
// C++17 version
template <typename... Args>
std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<std::is_convertible<Args, A*>...>>
    f(Args&&... args);
```

In C++11, replace `enable_if_t<X>` with `typename enable_if<X>::type`, and replace `std::conjunction_v` with your own `all` function.

Comment: Is there a document describing this? I can't find it.

"A* args is an ordinary declarator without a template parameter pack. Therefore, the ... is interpreted as declaring a variadic function (i.e., the va_args way) instead of a variadic template. This declaration is equivalent to:int P(A* args, ...)“

Comment: @ddwolf Of course, [dcl.fct] has a note that states that http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#footnote-90

Answer (score 1):

`int P(A* args ...)` is alternative syntax for `int P(A* args, ...)` so C ellipsis.

variadic template syntax is:

```
template <typename T>
void P(T*... args)
{
    int dummy [] = {0, ((std::cout << args << " "), 0)...};
    static_cast<void>(dummy); // Silent warning for unused variable
}
```

C++17 have better syntax with fold expression.

In your case, it seems you only want same argument type, so you can use `std::initializer_list` and have

```
void P(std::initializer_list<A> args) {
    for(A *m: args) {
      std::cout << m->a << " ";
    }
  }
```

and change at call site:

```
AA[0].P({AA+1, AA+2, AA+3, AA+4});
```

Comment: "int P(A* args ...) is alternative syntax for int P(A* args, ...) so C ellipsis.", I think this is reasonable, bug I cant find the official document describing this